# Android Studio setting 'next' textview for landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I am trying to set it up such that when I click the 'next' button when in landscape mode it actually moves to the next textview. The 'nextfocus' properties seem to have no effect on this button. Below is my screenshot.

[image]

Comment: could you post your layout (.xml) file?

Answer (score 0):

try with android:imeOptions="actionNext"